# minimum number of adjacent swaps to rid a string of a specific two-letter word's instances

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

How can I get started at finding a recursive/dynamic solution to the problem?

For example, how many adjacent swaps is at least needed to convert the given string `abaaccbabaabcab` (representing all other characters as `c`) to one without any instances of "ab"? It's elusive for me to come up with a way of breaking the problem into (independent) sub-problems.

For strings consisting of only `a`s and `b`s, the problem reduces to taking all `b`s before `a`s, but it becomes complicated with other characters involved.

PS: Can we assert that in at least one scenario of minimum swapping, swaps do not go beyond any block of `c...c`, where ... simply consists of a pile of `a`s and `b`s? In that case, `a`s either place after `b`s, or before first `c`, depending on which is closer. Vice versa for `b`s.

Is it a good place to start?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would take a look at the levenshtein edit-distance algorithm, and reduce it's logic to only swaps as specified in your question.

Comment: It might help to post a few pathological examples, such as `aaabb`, to give people something on which to chew.

Comment: Add some examples and what you expect as result.

Comment: Have you any ideas yet? Share **your** findings.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think it's really clear what the problem asks for, and I myself haven't any clear idea of how to solve systematically for any given string though.

Comment: One more edge case to consider: If the two given letters are equal (say, both `a`), then sometimes there's a solution (like for `aab`) and sometimes there's not (like for `aaa`).

Comment: You're right, thanks for mentioning. Let's assume that letters are distinct.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest tackling this not as a dynamic programming problem, but as a pathfinding algorithm.

Consider the graph whose nodes are all possible arrangements of the letters, with edges connecting arrangements that can be reached from each other with an adjacent swap.  You want to find the shortest path from your starting arrangement to any arrangement with no instances of the word.

We obviously don't want to write down the whole graph, but  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm doesn't require us to do so.  It only requires us to write down the nodes that we visit.  (Which we can do in a hash/dictionary/whatever your language calls it.)  The heuristic function that we can use is the number of instances of the forbidden word that are separated by at least one space.  This will work very well in simple cases.  If there is no solution, though, or on pathological cases like removing `ab` from `aaaaabbbbb`, we will visit the whole graph.  I don't know whether there is a way to avoid it.

But for a random English word in random gibberish, you should very quickly find provably minimal solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, if we only have instances of single `AB`s, separated by, an optimal solution could be to just reverse each one:

```
ABcABdhlkAB -> BAcBAdhlkBA
```

And if we have large separated blocks of `A`s followed by one or more `B`s, separated by another character, placing another character in between the blocks would be optimal:

```
AAAABBBBBcAAAABBBBBBBd -> AAAAcBBBBBAAAAdBBBBBBB
```

The challenge then is only when multiple sequential blocks of `A`s followed by `B`s are not surrounded by different characters:

```
AAAABBBBBAAAABBBBBAAAABBBBBAAAABBBBBAAAABBBBBqwer
```

If there are no other characters, the only solution is move all `B`s left of the `A`s. Otherwise, we have to find the optimal distribution of other characters to separate blocks of `A`s from blocks of `B`s that would result in the least cost coming from movement of `B` blocks left of `A` blocks.

Comment: I think you're on the right track, just a few observations: (1) If I understand what you mean by "joining `w` and `y`", then shifting `w` rightwards past all the `x`s (and all `x`s leftwards 1 position) is always at least as good as any move that involves shifting the leftmost `y` leftwards past one or more `x`s, since such a move requires further moves in the case where `[0 or more ys]` contains more `y`s. (2) You aren't yet considering the case where `w` = `y` -- in this case, moving `w` rightwards doesn't help.  (I am assuming you are implicitly assuming `w` != `x`.)